# Flask Apache mod_wsgi Endless page loading

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have /etc/apache2/sites-available/SpinnerApp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName 95.xxx.xxx.xx
            ServerAlias domain.ru

            WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/SpinnerApp/spinnerapp.wsgi
            WSGIDaemonProcess SpinnerApp user=www-data group=www-data threads=5

            <Directory /var/www/SpinnerApp/SpinnerApp/>
                    WSGIProcessGroup SpinnerApp
                    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                    WSGIScriptReloading On
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And /var/www/SpinnerApp/spinnerapp.wsgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys, logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)

activate_this = os.path.join('/var/www/SpinnerApp/SpinnerApp/spinnerenv', 'bin', 'activate_this.py')
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

sys.path.insert(0,'/var/www/SpinnerApp')

from SpinnerApp import app as application
```

But when input ip into browser page loadind without end. No errors in apache logs.

Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
<Directory /var/www/SpinnerApp/SpinnerApp/>
```

it should be:

```
<Directory /var/www/SpinnerApp>
```

That it worked at all suggests your overall Apache configuration may be mucked up as the access controls shouldn't have allowed the WSGI script in that location to be used at all with that being wrong.

Other implications of this mistake were that the code was running in embedded mode, which is not preferred arrangement. That is, wasn't using the daemon process group created. Also, the `WSGIApplicationGroup` directive wasn't being implied. This specific one is why you likely see the issue you do. That is, you are using a third party Python module which doesn't work in Python sub interpreters correctly. That directive avoids use of sub interpreters.

Also, the `ServerName` directive value shouldn't be an IP address but a hostname. Set it to the value you are using for `ServerAlias` and then delete the `ServerAlias` directive line.